# titlecase pipe in angular 4

Tags: angular, pipe

> Angular 4 introduced a new 'titlecase' pipe '|' and use to changes the first letter of each word into the uppercase.

The example as,

```
<h2>{{ 'ramesh rajendran` | titlecase }}</h2>
<!-- OUTPUT - It will display 'Ramesh Rajendran' -->
```

Is it possible in typescript code? And How?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Yes it is possible in TypeScript code. You'll need to call the Pipe's `transform()` method.

Your template:

```
<h2>{{ fullName }}</h2>
```

In your .ts:

```
import { TitleCasePipe } from '@angular/common';

export class App {

    fullName: string = 'ramesh rajendran';

    constructor(private titlecasePipe:TitleCasePipe ) { }

    transformName(){
        this.fullName = this.titlecasePipe.transform(this.fullName);
    }
}
```

You'll need to add `TitleCasePipe` in yout AppModule providers. You can call the transformation on button click or some other event in the typescript code.

Here is a link to [PLUNKER DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/zuqdWDkMDXF5U92ZYB9E?p=preview)

Comment: Hi Faisal. Note that the `>` quote block device has a special semantic meaning, which is that it encloses a "quote". That means something _quoted_ from a speaker, book, manual or other person/thing. If something is being written in your own voice, in general it is not a quote.

Comment: You'll need to add the TitleCasePipe class to the list of providers in your module:
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ],
  providers:[
    TitleCasePipe,
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }

Comment: You can also add TitleCasePipe in the component provider's list also: @Component({selector: 'name', templateUrl: 'component.html', providers: [TitleCasePipe]}); And import TitleCasePipe from @angular/common as well.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, you can use it like this

```html
<h2>{{ 'ramesh rajendran' | titlecase }}</h2>
```

But, don't forget to import `CommonModule` into your module.

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ...
  ],
```